# Is it possible for css grid items to stack in a single row?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to stack #2 & #4 together so it fits one cell of the grid? (code below)

(I'm working on some production wordpress posts so I can't modify the html output, only the css)

```css
.item3 { grid-column: auto / span 2; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;  
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px; 
}
.grid-container .item2, .grid-container .item4 { 
    height: 25px; 
    background: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="grid-container" style="">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is an image of what I want to achieve:
[image: Grid stack]

Comment: Please add a drawing of the intended palcement and layout. It is hard to udnerstand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, I uploaded an image now*